# countifs help required. date filter is not matching in countifs

Tags: excel

I tried to count the no. of cells which qualify 3 criteria however, it is not working in my case. Attached the Excel for your reference.

sheet1 first formula:
[image]

sheet1 second formula (which is not working):
[image]

Sheet2 table:
[image]

Comment: What do you actually want to return? It's not clear to me how TODAY() would fit in with multiple columns of data. I suspect you'll need INDEX and MATCH to get the right column to check the status in.

Comment: Thanks for replying. I want to return no.of success on particular date as per row 2..

Comment: You'll need something like: `=COUNTIFS(Sheet2!$A:$A,$A3,INDEX(Sheet2!$A:$AZ,0,match(TODAY(),Sheet2!$2:$2,0)),"Success")`

Comment: Sorry for the late but That was the perfect answer.. Now I'm getting what I need.. Thanks for your timely reply and help.

Comment: @rory can you help me on my other question asked in different forum..   question is "Countif unique occurrences of the text with criteria" .. or can you help me how should I solve if I have duplicate entries on the same day like success and failure.. (I want success if it has success and failure on the same day) .. can you help me on this.